# Why django template is not showing any output?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

So, here I was writing a simple news app using django, but template does not seem to be working,it's not showing any output that has been passed from `views.py`. 
I have checked `settings.py`,`INSTALLED_APPS` settings it's working

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse

import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen


def get_news():
    news_link = "https://news.google.com/news/rss"
    page = urlopen(news_link)
    xml_page = page.read()
    page.close()

    soup_page = soup(xml_page,"xml")
    news_list = soup_page.findAll("item")
    return news_list



def index(request):
    news_list = get_news()
    return render(request,'main/index.html',{'news_list' : news_list})
```

and template

```
    {% for news in news_list %}
    <h3> {{ news.title.text }} </h3>
    <h3> {{ news.pubDate.text }} </h3>
    {% endfor %}
```

If I pass any other data from render() dictionary, it is working but when passing lists,it's not showing any data in template

I tried checking if the list is None or empty but no,it's not empty.
Thank you!

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue because `urlopen(news_link)` fails for me. Using the python `requests` library, I can fetch the news_list and as far as I can see your code should work (except it should be `find_all()` not `findAll` and `news.pubdate` not `news.pubDate`. In your index view, try printing `[news.title for news in news_list]` to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got something like (`__str__` of bs4.element.Tag instance):

```
<title>lorem ipsum, dolor...</title>, <link>https://news.google.com/__i/rss/rd/articles/CBMiaGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmNubi5jb20vMjAyMC8wMi8wNS9wb2xpdGljcy9kb25hbGQtdHJ1bXAtbmFuY3ktcGVsb3NpLXN0YXRlLW9mLXRoZS11bmlvbi1hbmFseXNpcy9pbmRleC5odG1s0gFsaHR0cHM6Ly9hbXAuY25uLmNvbS9jbm4vMjAyMC8wMi8wNS9wb2xpdGljcy9kb25hbGQtdHJ1bXAtbmFuY3ktcGVsb3NpLXN0YXRlLW9mLXRoZS11bmlvbi1hbmFseXNpcy9pbmRleC5odG1s?oc=5</link>, <guid isPermaLink="false">52780574934659</guid>, <pubDate>Wed, 05 Feb 2020 08:15:00 GMT</pubDate>, <description>&lt;ol&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="https://news.google.com/__i/rss/rd/articles/CBMiaGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmNubi5jb20vMjAyMC8wMi8wNS9wb2xpdGljcy9kb25hbGQtdHJ1bXAtbmFuY3ktcGVsb3NpLXN0YXRlLW9mLXRoZS11bmlvbi1hbmFseXNpcy9pbmRleC5odG1s0gFsaHR0cHM6Ly9hbXAuY25uLmNvbS9jbm4vMjAyMC8wMi8wNS9wb2xpdGljcy9kb25hbGQtdHJ1bXAtbmFuY3ktcGVsb3NpLXN0YXRlLW9mLXRoZS11bmlvbi1hbmFseXNpcy9pbmRleC5odG1s?oc=5" target="_blank"&gt;Trump makes dazzling, divisive reelection pitch in State of the Union&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&lt;font color="#6f6f6f"&gt;CNN&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="https://news.google.com/__i/rss/rd/articles/CBMiK2h0dHBzOi8vd3d3LnlvdXR1YmUuY29tL3dhdGNoP3Y9QlNnYzd3dWlOMzDSAQA?oc=5" target="_blank"&gt;Nancy Pelosi rips up Trump's State of the Union speech&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&lt;font color="#6f6f6f"&gt;CNN&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="https://news.google.com/__i/rss/rd/articles/CBMiZWh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lm5iY25ld3MuY29tL3RoaW5rL29waW5pb24vc3RhdGUtdW5pb24taXNuLXQtc3Ryb25nLXRydW1wLXByZXRlbmRzLWl0LXMtYmV0dGVyLW5jbmExMTI5OTIx0gEtaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubmJjbmV3cy5jb20vdGhpbmsvYW1wL25jbmExMTI5OTIx?oc=5" target="_blank"&gt;The state of the union isn't as strong as Trump pretends, but it's better than Democrats say&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&lt;font color="#6f6f6f"&gt;NBC News&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="https://news.google.com/__i/rss/rd/articles/CBMicWh0dHBzOi8vbnlwb3N0LmNvbS8yMDIwLzAyLzA1L3N0YXRlLW9mLXRoZS11bmlvbi1hZGRyZXNzLXRydW1wLWhpdHMtZ3JhbmQtc2xhbS13aGlsZS1wZWxvc2ktanVzdC1sb29rcy1sb29rcy1zYWQv0gF1aHR0cHM6Ly9ueXBvc3QuY29tLzIwMjAvMDIvMDUvc3RhdGUtb2YtdGhlLXVuaW9uLWFkZHJlc3MtdHJ1bXAtaGl0cy1ncmFuZC1zbGFtLXdoaWxlLXBlbG9zaS1qdXN0LWxvb2tzLWxvb2tzLXNhZC9hbXAv?oc=5" target="_blank"&gt;State of the Union address: Trump hits grand slam, while Pelosi just looks looks sad&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&lt;font color="#6f6f6f"&gt;New York Post &lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href="https://news.google.com/__i/rss/rd/articles/CBMiZmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmZveG5ld3MuY29tL29waW5pb24vbGVzbGllLW1hcnNoYWxsLXNvdHUtYWRkcmVzcy1jb250aW51ZXMtdHJ1bXBzLXJvbGUtYXMtZGl2aWRlci1pbi1jaGllZtIBamh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmZveG5ld3MuY29tL29waW5pb24vbGVzbGllLW1hcnNoYWxsLXNvdHUtYWRkcmVzcy1jb250aW51ZXMtdHJ1bXBzLXJvbGUtYXMtZGl2aWRlci1pbi1jaGllZi5hbXA?oc=5" target="_blank"&gt;Leslie Marshall: SOTU address continues Trump’s role as divider in chief&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&lt;font color="#6f6f6f"&gt;Fox News&lt;/font&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;a href="https://news.google.com/stories/CAAqOQgKIjNDQklTSURvSmMzUnZjbmt0TXpZd1NoTUtFUWlEamE3N2pvQU1FU1YxUEo2emxrYWRLQUFQAQ?oc=5" target="_blank"&gt;View full coverage on Google News&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;</description>, <source url="https://www.cnn.com">CNN</source>
```

stored in `news`.

You can't access this instance with `{{ news.title.text }}`. That's why you end up with a empty result in your template. Try {{ news }} an you'll see what's in there.

Either you create a custom template filter, which can extract the necessary data from that instance --> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Or you prepare the data in your `get_news` method into a python structure `list of dicts`

Working example:

```
def get_news():
    news_link = "https://news.google.com/news/rss"
    page = urlopen(news_link)
    xml_page = page.read()
    page.close()

    soup_page = soup(xml_page, "xml")
    news_list = map(
        lambda item: {'title': item.title.text, 'date': item.pubDate.text},
        soup_page.findAll("item"))
    return news_list
```

And in the template:

```
    {% for news in news_list %}
        <h3> {{ news.title }} </h3>
        <h3> {{ news.date }} </h3>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: OP is using BeautifulSoup so `news` is a BeautifulSoup object (not a string), and yes, you can access the nodes using the tag name with `news.title`

Comment: Yes in Python `news.title` does work but I ran the code `{{ news.title }}` in the template doesn't work. I update the answer though, since you see the string representation of the instance not a string. I still suggest building the required structure in the backend

Comment: I added a working example, how the data structure may look like.

Answer (score 0):

In `news_list` you're getting `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>` beautiful soup object, that's why you are able to print it in views and not able to use it in templates.

You can use feedparser module as an alternative.

```
import feedparser
news_link = "https://news.google.com/news/rss"
print(feedparser.parse(news_link))
```